# Why can't I see the code generated by JIT?

Tags: java

I'm trying to see the code generated by Java JIT, while this is my `Main.java`:

```java
class Foo {
  public static int bar() { return 42; }
}
class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    System.exit(Foo.bar());
  }
}
```

I'm running this way:

```
$ javac Main.java && java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintOptoAssembly Main

============================= C2-compiled nmethod ==============================

============================= C2-compiled nmethod ==============================
```

Where is the code?

Comment: The method can only run once, you're not going to get JIT on a single execution of a method. The JVM immediately ends after that method.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you are right. I suggest you delete the comment and post an answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that under normal circumstances, code is initially interpreted and only JIT compiled when it is hot (called a lot, default is 10000).

To force code to be compiled immediately, use option `-Xcomp`, and then use `-XX:+PrintAssembly` (to be honest, the meaning of `-XX:+PrintOptoAssembly` is not entirely clear to me, except clearly, it doesn't seem to print assembly in this case ;).

In short, use:

```bash
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly -Xcomp Main
```